# Spring Security UTF-8 codpage with russian usernames

Tags: java, jsp, spring-security

I use SS.Users stored in mysql database. Database and Column charset is UTF-8  When i want give username for current login user in JSP page  i write:

< security:authentication property="principal.username"/ >

if username on english - all right, i get it username

but if username writen in russian language,for example "новый_пользователь", i get in page source code " & # 1085;& #1086;& #1074;& #1099;& #1081;& #95;& #1087;& #1086;& #1083;& #1100;& #1079;& #1086;& #1074;& #1072;& #1090;& #1077;& #1083;& #1100;"

how to fix it?
Thank you for your answers.

In my web.xml i have filter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>

    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>

        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Comment: What version are you using and how are you rendering the name?

Comment: SS - 3.1.0.RELEASE, I write in JSP <security:authentication property="principal.username"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authentication tag escapes the contents by default to reduce the risk of injection attacks. Try it with:

```
<security:authentication property="principal.username" htmlEscape="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

What page encoding your jsp use?

Try to add following lines to your **web.xml**:

```
 <jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
      <page-encoding>utf-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Comment: It does not give result( I Use UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

There are several points to attent to, so maybe read [Character Conversions from Browser to Database](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/HTTPCharset/), some of them server dependent.

I assume you did UTF-8 right, remains:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Which should be possible via a HTTP header [Accept-Charset: UTF-8](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.2) too.

*(This says that the server may accept characters instead of HTML entities `& # ... ;`)*

Comment: The browser gives everything as needed. But in the page code, I want to see Russian letters instead of their codes.

Comment: Is it not so, that the browser thinks it has to return for a form field value a numeric entity instead of a UTF-8 char? So accept-charset should inform the browser to simply return UTF-8.